# select certificate popup comes while calling web api deployed on service fabric from javascript

Tags: azure-service-fabric

we have web api deployed on service fabric cluster. When that api is getting called from javascript it pops up the select certificate window in browser. Can you please suggest how to avoid that? We are allowing to make calls to web api using bearer token.

Comment: Do you have [client certificate authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-3.1#get-started) enabled in the Web API?

Comment: nope, we are authentication via token

Answer (score 0):

while binding ssl cert, this field was being set - clientcertnegotiation=enable
And that was causing that issue